# setParameters Failed in Nexus 5 and Nexus 7

Tags: android, android-camera

I have implemented custom camera in my app. It is working fine in all device except Nexus 5 and Nexus 7. In both devices, It is crashing with SetParameters failed on camera. I have implemented custom camera with below code:

```java
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");
            Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
            if (mSupportedPreviewSizes != null) {
                mPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, w,
                        h);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged : mPreviewSize height:"
                    + mPreviewSize.height + " width: " + mPreviewSize.width);
            parameters.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);

            requestLayout();

            mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
            Log.e(TAG, "surfaceChanged called setParameters success");
        }
    }
```

I have found at many places comments that it is due to unsupported preview size but In my case, I am already taking it from supported preview sizes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a Nexus tablet: the same code changing the preview size to another supported preview size worked on various tablets but not the nexus tablet I had.

In my case, the issue was that I had already started previewing before changing the preview size. Changing the preview size before starting the preview size solved my issue.